# How to get version of `/usr/bin/time` command on macOS?

Tags: command-line, zsh, time

I'm struggling to find out what version of `/usr/bin/time` I have, on my M1 macOS 13.2.

`/usr/bin/time` seems to have no help beyond a usage string (that has options for *help* nor *version*).

This is what I get when trying various things:

```bash
$ /usr/bin/time -v
/usr/bin/time: illegal option -- v
```

When I type `man time`, I get some docs that say at the bottom:

```
STANDARDS
     The time utility is expected to conform to ISO/IEC 9945-2:1993
     (``POSIX'').

HISTORY
     A time utility appeared in Version 3 AT&T UNIX.

macOS 13.2                     January 15, 2021                     macOS 13.2
```

The "version" seems to be macOS 13.2 (January 15, 2021) then? But I'm not sure which exact man page is pulled in when I type `man time` as there are in-built commands for `time` as well in `bash` and `zsh`. How can I be sure that this *is* the man page for `/usr/bin/time`.

Comment: You were closed on SO because it isn't specifically a programming question, but rather to be OS related. They're very strict about that. It could be argued your question could be in the context of system administration.

Comment: `man` doesn’t know about internal commands of bash/zsh, so `man time` always shows the man page of the `time` binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `time` command included with macOS is open source. For macOS 13.2, the links start [here](https://opensource.apple.com/releases/). Follow the GitHub link for `shell_cmds-278` to [here](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/shell_cmds/tree/shell_cmds-278), then the folder `time` to [here](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/shell_cmds/tree/shell_cmds-278/time) and you will find the man page source `time.1` and the source `time.c`

You can download the man page source and enter the command `man ./time.1` to view a formatted version of the downloaded man page.

BTW, there is no version to be found in the source code `time.c`.

Comment: Have you ever tried using `what` as in- `what /usr/bin/time` ?

Comment: [`what`](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/what/) – show what versions of object modules were used to construct a file

Comment: @fd0: I have spent huge amounts of time search the open source for code without knowing the `what` command would have told me where to look. Nuts.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask `which time` you get `time: shell reserved word`. It is documented in the man page for your shell e.g.

```
% man zshmisc
...
 time [ pipeline ]
              The pipeline is executed, and timing statistics are reported on the standard error in the form specified by the TIMEFMT parameter.  If
              pipeline is omitted, print statistics about the shell process and its children.
```

`man time` specifically references `/usr/bin/time` in the text. So it's fair to assume that's how the docs match up.

Using `/usr/bin/time` options with the builtin throws errors, so I'm not sure if they are identical. If you need the options, use `/usr/bin/time` explicitly.

As to the versions, I would suggest the builtin version is that of the shell, and `/usr/bin/time` corresponds to your macOS version for the lack of any `-v` option.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion! Apparently the man pages live entirely separately from binaries. I was hoping there would be a way to get man pages for a specific executable specified by exact path but alas no - unless I'm missing something.